# Sendgrid handlebar template array length

Tags: templates, handlebars.js, sendgrid

I'm trying to fetch length of an array but it seems length only exists for conditionals.

Data:

```
{
    "array": ["a", "b", "c"]
}
```

in sendgrid template:

```
{{array.length}}
```

and nothing is rendered in the email (preview renders it correctly).

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it looks like you can use the [`greaterThan`](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/using-handlebars#length) tag

Example from Sendgrid docs:

```
<p>
Hello Ben!
{{#greaterThan (length cartItems) 0}}
 It looks like you still have some items in your shopping cart. Sign back in to continue checking out at any time.
{{else}}
 Thanks for browsing our site. We hope you'll come back soon.
{{/greaterThan}}
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the length helper.

```
{{length array}}
```

[Sendgrid documentation : Length helper](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/using-handlebars?locale=en#length)